# How do I find out the UBootloader address of a Raspberry PI B?

Tags: boot, freebsd, boot-loader, arm

From the cross-compiling documentation of FreeBSD they mention:

> A detail left out of the simple build example above is the
>   UBLDR_LOADADDR=0xnnnnnnnn value which must be provided on the
>   buildworld command line. This is a tedious little detail currently
>   required for ARM systems. The loader(8) flavor used on most ARM
>   systems is 'ubldr' (U-Boot loader), and it currently has to be linked
>   at a fixed address. The address is different for every board or
>   system. Typically the address is whatever the U-Boot on your system
>   has set in its loadaddr environment variable.

https://wiki.freebsd.org/FreeBSD/arm/crossbuild#Pesky%20Details

Where can I find this for my [ARMv6 device](https://www.pololu.com/product/2750/specs) to ensure that it will boot after I compile it to an SD Card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to find this info is asking on IRC, or searching at the FreeBSD Wiki for the board desired to create a cross-compiled image: [Building an image for Raspberry Pi 2](https://wiki.freebsd.org/FreeBSD/arm/Raspberry%20Pi%202%20image)

```
# mount /dev/md0s2a /mnt
# make TARGET_ARCH=armv6 UBLDR_LOADADDR=0x2000000 buildworld
# make TARGET_ARCH=armv6 KERNCONF=RPI2 buildkernel
# make TARGET_ARCH=armv6 DESTDIR=/mnt installkernel
# make TARGET_ARCH=armv6 DESTDIR=/mnt installworld distribution
```

Comment: If I do a cross-compile, do I have to use FreeBSD to do it?  Or can I just use a Linux distro instead?  (of course I can always just boot a VM and do it there)

Comment: All device naming and files on those tutorials are from FreeBSD so, i assume that having a FreeBSD amd64 is the safest way to do it. Also, these tutorials talk about using a custom source directory tree and not the `/usr/src` FreeBSD directory, another clue that will lead to FreeBSD workstation doing cross-compilation. Maybe, you will have to do some changes to make this work(if it will work) on a Linux station.